# How to set up user accounts with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, accounts

I'm trying to set up user accounts with my Meteor app. Right now I have the login and register forms made, but they don't work. Does anyone know how to do this? Here is the code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/5AMWE5T/X8aJf/1/

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <form id="login-form" action="/">
            <div>
                <input type="email" id="login-email" />
                <input type="password" id="login-password" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="login-button" value="Sign in" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="register-box">
        <form id="register-form" action="action">
            <div>
                <input type="username" id="account-username" placeholder=" Username" />
                <input type="email" id="account-email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="password" id="account-password" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="create-account" value="Sign up" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#topbar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #47a7d3;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#register-form {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#account-username {
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    border-width: 0.1em;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    width: 15.4em;
    margin-left: 0.1em;
    height: 1.8em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.1em #676767;
}
#login-form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0.3em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    right: 0.33em;
    text-align: right;
}
#login-email {
    width: 180px;
}
#login-password {
    width: 100px;
}
#login-button {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    font-family:'Montserrat Alternates';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
```

javascript:

```
Template.login.events({

    'submit #login-form': function (e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // retrieve the input field values
        var email = t.find('#login-email').value,
            password = t.find('#login-password').value;

        // Trim and validate your fields here.... 

        var trimInput = function (val) {
            return val.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
        }
        var email = trimInput(email);
        // If validation passes, supply the appropriate fields to the
        // Meteor.loginWithPassword() function.
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err) {
            if (err)
            // The user might not have been found, or their password
            // could be incorrect. Inform the user that their
            // login attempt has failed.
            console.log("Your email or password are incorrect")
            else
            // The user has been logged in.
            console.log("You have been logged in!")
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you do meteor add accounts-password?

Answer (score 1):

Your code wouldn't work with a fiddle btw.

A couple of things:

Make sure you have `accounts-password` installed you can do this with `meteor add accounts-password`

You haven't given the code for registrations but assuming you use an email for registration, you should log in this way with the {email: email}.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword({email: email, password, function (err) {
```

It would also be a bit more helpful if you gave a bit more info on how you feel it doesn't work. Does submitting the page refresh the page? Do you have any javascript errors in your console? Do you get an error message back?

Comment: When you submit the page refreshes but nothing else happens.

Comment: This is because your `e.preventDefault()` isnt stopping the page propogation. You will notice that even without the form submit handler it will also do this. Check that you can capture the event first, you might have a typo somewhere or something which is preventing the event being bound.